# No stream fusion with unsafeUpdate_ in unboxed vector

Tags: haskell, vector, stream, fusion

Is it possible to maintain stream fusion when processing a `vector` if `unsafeUpdate_` function is used to update some elements of a `vector`? The answer seems to be no in the test I did. For the code below, temporary vector is generated in `upd` function, as confirmed in the core:

```
module Main where
import Data.Vector.Unboxed as U

upd :: Vector Int -> Vector Int
upd v = U.unsafeUpdate_ v (U.fromList [0]) (U.fromList [2])

sum :: Vector Int -> Int
sum = U.sum . upd

main = print $ Main.sum $ U.fromList [1..3]
```

In the core, `$wupd` function is used in `sum` - as seen below, it generates new `bytearray`:

```
$wupd :: Vector Int -> Vector Int
$wupd =
  \ (w :: Vector Int) ->
    case w `cast` ... of _ { Vector ipv ipv1 ipv2 ->
    case main11 `cast` ... of _ { Vector ipv3 ipv4 ipv5 ->
    case main7 `cast` ... of _ { Vector ipv6 ipv7 ipv8 ->
    runSTRep
      (\ (@ s) (s :: State# s) ->
         case >=# ipv1 0 of _ {
           False -> case main6 ipv1 of wild { };
           True ->
             case newByteArray# (*# ipv1 8) (s `cast` ...)
             of _ { (# ipv9, ipv10 #) ->
             case (copyByteArray# ipv2 (*# ipv 8) ipv10 0 (*# ipv1 8) ipv9)
                  `cast` ...
```

There is a nice, tight loop in the core for `sum` function but just before that loop, there is a call to `$wupd` function, and so, a temporary generation.

Is there a way to avoid temporary generation in the example here? The way I think about it, updating a vector in index i is the case of parsing a stream but only acting on the stream in index i (skipping the rest), and replacing the element there with another element. So, updating a vector in an arbitrary location shouldn't break stream fusion, right?

Comment: Aside: `yarr` supports fusion and unrolling along with in-place changing: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yarr/1.3.1/doc/html/Data-Yarr-Repr-Foreign.html#t:F

Comment: @leventov, very nice! Since you seem to be the author of that library, would you be able to share how to write in-place fusible update function for vector example above? Surely, what you did for yarr should be applicable here, no?

Comment: big, big drawback of `yarr-1.*` it is tightly connected with IO. In-place editing is just `do { ... write arr 0 2; ... }`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't be 100% sure, because with [`vector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) it's turtles all the way down (you never really reach the actual implementation, there's always another indirection), but as far as I understand it, the `update` variants force a new temporary through cloning:

```
unsafeUpdate_ :: (Vector v a, Vector v Int) => v a -> v Int -> v a -> v a
{-# INLINE unsafeUpdate_ #-}
unsafeUpdate_ v is w
  = unsafeUpdate_stream v (Stream.zipWith (,) (stream is) (stream w))

unsafeUpdate_stream :: Vector v a => v a -> Stream (Int,a) -> v a
{-# INLINE unsafeUpdate_stream #-}
unsafeUpdate_stream = modifyWithStream M.unsafeUpdate
```

and `modifyWithStream` calls `clone` (and `new`),

```
modifyWithStream :: Vector v a
                 => (forall s. Mutable v s a -> Stream b -> ST s ())
                 -> v a -> Stream b -> v a
{-# INLINE modifyWithStream #-}
modifyWithStream p v s = new (New.modifyWithStream p (clone v) s)

new :: Vector v a => New v a -> v a
{-# INLINE_STREAM new #-}
new m = m `seq` runST (unsafeFreeze =<< New.run m)

-- | Convert a vector to an initialiser which, when run, produces a copy of
-- the vector.
clone :: Vector v a => v a -> New v a
{-# INLINE_STREAM clone #-}
clone v = v `seq` New.create (
  do
    mv <- M.new (length v)
    unsafeCopy mv v
    return mv)
```

and I see no way that `vector` would get rid of that `unsafeCopy` again.

Comment: according to this [vector recycling paper](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~rl/publications/recycling.pdf), clone/new are supposed to fuse together though I don't see it in my experiments.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change one or very few elements, there are nice solutions in `repa` and `yarr` libraries. They preserve fusion (I'm not sure about `repa`) and Haskell-idiomatic.

Repa, using [`fromFunction`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/repa/3.2.3.3/doc/html/Data-Array-Repa.html#v%3afromFunction):

```
upd arr = fromFunction (extent arr) ix
  where ix (Z .: 0) = 2
        ix i = index arr i
```

Yarr, using [`Delayed`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yarr/1.3.1/doc/html/Data-Yarr-Repr-Delayed.html#t%3aD):

```
upd arr = Delayed (extent arr) (touchArray arr) (force arr) ix
  where ix 0 = return 2
        ix i = index arr i
```